# Custom shape ListView

Tags: android, listview, customization

There are many questions that have been answered on this topic. But I am still not able to find out apt solution for my problem.

Here it is :
I have created custom list item by applying gradient and I have also created custom shape for listview background, but list item is overlapping on listview shape and the shape is not visible.

Is there anything I am missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The shape is the shape of the background, not of the actual listview. The listview items are on top of the background, so they will cover it up. You can try adding transparency to the items, spacing them out, etc.

Comment: Ok, but list items have their own selector.